# For what kind of values is $x^x$ defined in quadrants other than the first?

Tags: calculus, functions

[image: WolframAlpha's plot of y=x^x]

The function $x^x$ should be discontinuous for negative values, but the WolframAlpha does not present it as so. Can someone explain the graph for me (including the imaginary part)?

Comment: The values for $-0.5^{-0.5}$ and $-1^{-1}=-1$ are clear to you?

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: @Matthias First of all, if x takes the value of -0.5, the output should be (-0.5)^(-0.5). I am not exactly sure whether this is defined or not. My question is asking for consideration of irrational numbers. What is the meaning of a irrational number to the power of itself? The negative domain is definitely not continuous, then why would the plot appear to show a trend? Can you explain the trend?

Comment: $(-0.5)^{-0.5}=\sqrt{-2}=i\sqrt2$